# Hiding tab headers in tabControl in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I'm trying to hide tab headers in the tabControl, like it's shown here in  [this link](http://blog.laplante.io/2011/01/hiding-tab-headers-on-a-tabcontrol-in-c/), but I am getting an error in the designer's code. Once I change both lines, I get this:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Message     The designer cannot process unknown name 'SelectedIndex' at line 43.  The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified.  Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again.     c:\users\krzysztof\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DaneUzytkownika3\DaneUzytkownika3\TabController.Designer.cs    44
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS1061  'TabController' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedIndex' and no extension method 'SelectedIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'TabController' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   DaneUzytkownika3    c:\users\krzysztof\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DaneUzytkownika3\DaneUzytkownika3\TabController.Designer.cs    43

Line 43 in the designer's code of the form is:

```
this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Could someone please tell me, how do I fix it?

---

TablessTabControl.cs

```
namespace hiding
{
    class TablessTabControl : Form1
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            // Hide tabs by trapping the TCM_ADJUSTRECT message
            if (m.Msg == 0x1328 && !DesignMode)
                m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
            else
                base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.Designer.cs

```
namespace hiding
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.tabControl1 = new TablessTabControl();
            //this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
            this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.tabPage2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tabControl1
            // 
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
            this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 12);
            this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
            this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;//line with the error
            this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
            this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // tabPage1
            // 
            this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
            this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
            this.tabPage1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(192, 74);
            this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.tabPage1.Text = "tabPage1";
            this.tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // tabPage2
            // 
            this.tabPage2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
            this.tabPage2.Name = "tabPage2";
            this.tabPage2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tabPage2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(192, 74);
            this.tabPage2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.tabPage2.Text = "tabPage2";
            this.tabPage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private TablessTabControl tabControl1;
        //private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a project and implemented the tab control as given in your example as follows:

```
class TablessTabControl : TabControl
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Hide tabs by trapping the TCM_ADJUSTRECT message
        if (m.Msg == 0x1328 && !DesignMode)
            m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
        else
            base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Then upon rebuilding the project I add my new `TablessTabControl` to a test form using the designer.  Within the designer, I can switch between the tabs using the visible headers.

At runtime, the headers disappear as intended.  I have two tabs; I am able to select between the tabs by using the following code:

```
// Selects the first tab:
tablessTabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;

// Selects the second tab:
tablessTabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

---

Additionally, in `Form1.Designer.cs`, I have line `48` as follows:

```
this.tablessTabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

which poses no difficulty for me.

Have you tried closing all documents, cleaning the solution, rebuilding and reopening the designer?

Comment: Tried all the steps you suggested, but nothing changed :(

Comment: Strange.  But I did notice in your error report it says `TabController` lacks the `SelectedIndex` definition, not the inherited tab control itself.  Can you try removing that line from the designer code where it sets the selected index?  But in any case, `tabControl1` should be an instance of `YourTabControl` or `TablessTabControl`, not `TabController`.

Comment: Uhm... When I remove it, I get an error window instead of the designers view. Well `TabController` is my form that I made, is it still wrong? Now I noticed the differences between mine and yours code, I pasted the code in my form TabController.cs is that bad? `public partial class TabController : Form
    {` and then the code comes. Or should I just create an extra class?

Comment: The original code for `TablessTabControl` which inherits from `TabControl` goes in its own class file.  In fact, I would suggest you do that in a new solution, then rebuild all.  You will then see `TablessTabControl` in the toolbox.  Add it to the default Form1 and then take a look at the designer.  You should see where the differences are.

Comment: Okay, I've done TablessTabControl class that inherits from the first form. But I do still get the same error, lol. Are you first adding the normal tabController, then changing the designer code values and then go to designer view again? Because at this point I get the error.. Umm... All the time trying to work it out, but I'm stuck, it's probably something very stupid.

Comment: I have updated my question and added the code, if it will be easier to find the problem.

Comment: You have `TablessTabControl` inheriting from `Form1`, it should inherit from `TabControl`.

Comment: Oh my god. I feel so ashamed now. I am so sorry. Thank you for your help, and mostly for your patience. Everything works fine!

Comment: No problem!  Glad to help!